# How to get first two occurrences using LINQ?

Tags: performance, linq, entity-framework-4

I need to know the number of elements that satisfy a condition so I perform the following:

```
int numberOfItems = context.SomeEntity.Count(someCondition);
```

but as I only need to check if, and only if, numberOfItems is exactly 1, I would like to improve this query and be more efficient by stopping counting items when first two occurrences satisfy the condition (when first 2 occurrences are encountered that satisfy the condition, there is no need to continue checking it). Performing something like:

```
bool existsOnlyOne = context.SomeEntity....
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: From experience the Single() method is one of the fastest ways to achieve this, but that would involve exception driven development (which would be bad).  You could crack open the code for Single() and see what you find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the condition to

```
bool existsOnlyOne = context.SomeEntity.Where(someCondition).Take(2).Count() == 1;
```

If you have more than two items, the items from the third one on would be ignored by the `Take(2)` method.